# InputStream is = App.class.getResourceAsStream("test.properties");

Tags: java

the returned InputStream is null. What will be the possible cause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`App.class.getResourceAsStream(resource)` searches for the resource in the same hierarchy as the class (so if your `App` class is in package `com.yourcompany`, this would search for the resource `com/yourcompany/test.properties`). In your situation you either have to prepend a slash or use the classloader instead of the class:

a)

```
App.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.properties")
```

b)

```
App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties")
```

Comment: For me, the files were not in the jar. Clean/re-building the app solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The "actual dir" is in the folder/package your class is in. Correct usage:

```
InputStream is = App.class.getResourceAsStream(“../../test.properties”);
```

Or maybe:

```
InputStream is = App.class.getResourceAsStream(“/test.properties”);
```

Comment: +1 for ../ This can sometimes be helpful and noone else thought about it

Answer (score 1):

The file `test.properties` was not found.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is usually that the file could not be found. (Rarely, it is that your app does not have read permission.) Typical problems here are that you need a leading path indicator (perhaps just `/`). I believe that the default search is based on the class loader for the App class and is probably not what you want.

Comment: my class is at com/busy/, my properties is  at the root directory.anything wrong?

Comment: The root directory of what? Your project or the file system? (It has to be part of your project to be opened with getResourceAsStream.) Put a leading `/` on the file name and see what happens. From what you describe, it will likely work.

Answer (score 1):

> how to make sure ./test.properties is on the classpath?

I assume that you actually know what the classpath is, and how it is set.  And what a classloader it.  If so, read on ...

The class path defines a namespace of resources with hierarchical names like "/a/b/c/d", or  "/some/pkg/SomeClass.class".  I'll call this the *classloader namespace*.  When you call the `getResourceAsStream(path)` method, you are telling the classloader to locate the resource whose path is given by `path` in the classloader namespace ... and return an bytestream for reading the resource.

There are two kinds of path that you can give: absolute paths start with a "/", and relative paths start with some other character than "/".

- If you use an absolute path (e.g. "/a/b/test.properties", then you will get the resource whose absolute path in the classloader namespace is the same as the path that you gave.
- If you use a relative path (e.g. "test.properties"), then the relative path is resolved relative to the context in which you are loading it.  In this case you are using

  ```
  import some.pkg.App;  // for instance

  App.class.getResourceAsStream("test.properties");
  ```

  The context for resolving the pathname will be the pathname for the `App` classes package; i.e. "/some/pkg".  Hence, the classloader will look for a resource whose absolute name in the namespace is "/some/pkg/test.properties".  (Note that the mapping from a package name to a pathname in the classloader namespace involves replacing the "." separators in the package FQN with "/" separators.)

  On the other handler if you use a classloader handle directly to load a resource; e.g.

  ```
  App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties");
  ```

  the classloader uses "/" as its context, so the above will resolve to "/test.properties" ... in the namespace.

This should tell you how to work out where to put the "test.properties" file so that it can be located by the call you are using.  Alternatively, you could use an absolute name.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such thing should make practice to put all your properties file under root context.
So that you can access them from any child folder by

```
App.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.properties")
```